# Balls in baskets

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

There are 16 baskets: 4 red, 4 blue, 4 green and 4 black. Each basket contains a ball from one of the 4 colours (see image). You can pick up a ball from one basket and swap it with a ball from another basket. What is least number of swaps needed to make every basket contain a ball of the same colour as the basket?

[image]

Comment: Don't you hate it when a puzzle requires so much longer to make (and draw!) than to solve? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the baskets are named with the rows and columns:

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

I will first try and swap the baskets' containers where the two will be solved with just 1 swap:

> `A<->E, J<->K, F<->O, G<->P`

Then finish the puzzle with the smallest number of swaps:

> `D<->L, D<->H, B<->D`

So the smallest number of swaps needed is

> 7 swaps!

***EDIT:*** `<->` is a swap, e.g. `A<->B` is basically swapping whatever's in A to B.

Comment: That is correct! Well done and welcome to Puzzling.